# How can I iterate over list of URL's to scrape the data in Scrapy?

Tags: url, scrapy, scrape

```
import scrapy
class oneplus_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='one_plus'
    page_number=0
    start_urls=[
        'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=samsung+mobile&page=3&qid=1600763713&ref=sr_pg_3'
    ]
     
    def parse(self,response):
        all_links=[]
        total_links=[]
        domain='https://www.amazon.com'
        href=[]
        link_set=set()
        
        href=response.css('a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal').xpath('@href').extract()
        for x in href:
            link_set.add(domain+x)
        for x in link_set:
            next_page=x
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse_page1)


    def parse_page1(self, response):
        title=response.css('span.a-size-large product-title-word-break::text').extract()
        print(title)
```

Error after running the code - (failed 2 times): 503 Service Unavailable.
I tried many ways but failed. Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check url by "curl" first. like,

```
curl -I "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=samsung+mobile&page=3&qid=1600763713&ref=sr_pg_3"
```

then, you can see 503 response.

```
HTTP/2 503
```

In other words, your request is wrong.

you have to find proper request.

Chrome DevTools will help you. like

[image]

I think that user-agent ( like browser ) must be needed.

```
curl 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=samsung+mobile&page=3&qid=1600763713&ref=sr_pg_3' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36' \
   --compressed
```

so... It may work,

```
import scrapy
class oneplus_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='one_plus'
    page_number=0
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"
    start_urls=[
        'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=samsung+mobile&page=3&qid=1600763713&ref=sr_pg_3'
    ]
     
    def parse(self,response):
        all_links=[]
        total_links=[]
        domain='https://www.amazon.com'
        href=[]
        link_set=set()
        
        href=response.css('a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal').xpath('@href').extract()
        for x in href:
            link_set.add(domain+x)
        for x in link_set:
            next_page=x
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse_page1)


    def parse_page1(self, response):
        title=response.css('span.a-size-large product-title-word-break::text').extract()
        print(title)
```

Comment: I put the user_agent and now it's visiting the next page links but not returning the text on that page. Here is the output.                                                                                                          2020-09-23 15:25:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/Samsung-Unlocked-Smartphone-Technology-Long-Lasting/dp/B08DP5BZK4/ref=sr_1_39?dchild=1&keywords=samsung+mobile&qid=1600763713&sr=8-39> (referer: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=samsung+mobile&page=3&qid=1600763713&ref=sr_pg_3)
[]
[]
[]